# Why does a singular matrix have a (non-zero) eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is clear that given a matrix A, if there is a non-zero vector v such that Av=0, then A is not invertible. However, if a matrix A has determinant zero, how would you show that there exists a vector v such that Av=0 and v is not 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the matrix is invertible, then you can use gaussian elimination to transform it to an upper triangular one which has nonzero determinant; hence the original matrix had nonzero determinant as well. So, if the determinant is zero, the matrix is singular. You can easily show that a singular matrix has linearly dependent columns, so some $\sum_j A_{\cdot, j}\, x_j=0$, $A_{\cdot, j}$ denoting the $j$-the column of the matrix. So, for $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)^T$, you get that $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is invertible iff $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution $x=0$.

Hence, if $A$ is not invertible then there is $x\ne 0$ such that $Ax=0$. This $x$ is an eigenvector (for the eigenvalue $0$).

Comment: But how would you show that if Ax = 0 only has the solution x= 0 then A is invertible (i.e. if A is not invertible then Ax = 0 has a non-trivial solution)?

Answer (score 0):

Because if the determinant is $0$ then $0$ is an eigenvalue (because the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues) then $A-0I=A$ (where $A$ is your matrix and $I$ the identity matrix) has a non-trivial kernel, then exists a $v\neq0$ such that $Av=0$

Comment: How do you show A has a non-trivial kernel?

Comment: The determinant is zero if and only if there exists a linear combination, encoded in $v$ such that $Av=0$. I think what you are really asking is a proof of the properties of the determinant.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thanks.